# .htaccess issues with redirecting and authuser for wp-login.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We switched our domain/site and have been redirecting traffic from our old site to the new but we are keeping our Wordpress blog on the old site via .htaccess. In the Wordpress we have another .htaccess to password protect the 'wp-login.php' but if it's active then it redirects requests to our new site.

/home/user/public_html/.htaccess

```
# -FrontPage-
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|blog/wp-admin.php|blog/wp-admin|blog/wp-login.php)
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newwebsite.com/

AuthUserFile /home/user/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/user/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp


# Begin password protection #
# End password protection #
...
```

/home/user/public_html/blog/.htaccess

```
<Files wp-login.php>
AuthUserFile /home/user/public_html/blog/.htpasswd
AuthName "Private access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Files>
```

How do I keep protecting wp-login and allow it to redirect properly?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should work. The `.htaccess` file in your root is processed first and will redirect to your new site if there is no match. If a redirect isn't performed and the `/blog/wp-login.php` page is loaded, your second `.htaccess` file should process triggering the Basic Auth prompt.

Your `.htaccess` redirect can be simplified as well since you only need to make sure the URL path doesn't start with `/blog/`. If there is no match you can just redirect to the new site using a `.` match.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule . http://www.newwebsite.com/
```